# Change US time to Italy Time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem, my database server is in USA and my user is in Italy.
when it insert in to my site than US time is show.
I have to retrieve date from database using getdate() function.
so what i do for change US Time to Italy time in to my database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN docs on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), the conversion style no. 105 is for Italy - so try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 105)
```

But in your SQL Server database table, it's always stored as a `DATETIME` (I hope!), and the `DATETIME` doesn't have any *format* or anything associated with it - it's just an 8-byte numerical value. So you definitely shouldn't have to do anything about **storing** the data - it's only when you're **displaying it** (using a `SELECT` or something) where you have to make sure to output it in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

The date format is related to the database [Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

It's not trivial to change the collation once the database is setup.

Here are the instructions from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254%28SQL.100%29.aspx):

> ```
> Make sure you have all the information or scripts needed to re-create your user databases and all the objects in them.
>
> Export all your data using a tool such as the bcp Utility. For more information, see Importing and Exporting Bulk Data.
>
> Drop all the user databases.
>
> Rebuild the master database specifying the new collation in the SQLCOLLATION property of the setup command. For example:
>
> Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName 
> /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[ SAPWD= StrongPassword ] 
> /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName
>
> For more information, see Rebuilding System Databases.
>
> Create all the databases and all the objects in them.
>
> Import all your data.
> ```

Otherwise, you'd need to convert the date to the format required once you've pulled it out of the database. If you're likely to display multiple date formats, you'd need to do this anyway. And this would normally be done in the application layer rather than in SQL.